# Mastermind placing pawns when not needed C# algotirm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to create a Mastermind game for school. We run against some problems:

" Game explaination:

- Correct place & color: Black Pawn
- Correct color BUT wrong place: White Pawn "

Our problem:
The game checks for black pawns, when black pawns placed it will also check the same one for white.
[image: The error]

Our code is as following:

```
//1 = Blue
//2 = Green
//3 = Yellow
//4 = Red

int kleur1 = rnd.Next(1, 5);
int kleur2 = rnd.Next(1, 5);
int kleur3 = rnd.Next(1, 5);
int kleur4 = rnd.Next(1, 5);

if (keuze1_1 == kleur1){
 //Place black pawn
}
if (keuze1_2 == kleur2){
 //Place black pawn
}
if (keuze1_3 == kleur3){
 //Place black pawn
}
if (keuze1_4 == kleur4){
 //Place black pawn
}

if (keuze1_1 != kleur1 && keuze1_1 == kleur2 || keuze1_1 == kleur3 || keuze1_1 == kleur4 && kleur1 != kleur2 && kleur1 != kleur3 && kleur1 != kleur4){
 //Place white pawn
}

if (keuze1_2 != kleur2 && keuze1_2 == kleur1 || keuze1_2 == kleur3 || keuze1_2 == kleur4 && kleur2 != kleur1 && kleur2 != kleur3 && kleur2 != kleur4){
 //Place white pawn
}

 if (keuze1_3 != kleur3 && keuze1_3 == kleur2 || keuze1_3 == kleur1 || keuze1_3 == kleur4 && kleur3 != kleur2 && kleur3 != kleur1 && kleur3 != kleur4){
 //Place white pawn
}

if (keuze1_4 != kleur4 && keuze1_4 == kleur3 || keuze1_4 == kleur2 || keuze1_4 == kleur1 && kleur4 != kleur3 && kleur4 != kleur2 && kleur4 != kleur1){
 //Place white pawn
}

if (keuze1_1 == kleur1 && keuze1_2 == kleur2 && keuze1_3 == kleur3 && keuze1_4 == kleur4){
  //CORRECT!!
}
```

Please help it's placing white pawn when they are not required!

Patrick!

Comment: Break points are you friends https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx

Comment: if its checking for white also - change your logic to stop it :)

Comment: Specifically, your `black` check needs to flag matched positions so that those can be excluded from `white` checking.

Comment: Incidentally, your logic will become much cleaner if you use arrays and loops instead of discrete variables.

Comment: Like said before, your checks for the white pawns are not excluding the logic you're using to check black pawns. It's placing white pawns for colors you have checked for black. Try to create functions that check 1 position for the set of choices, one funciton for checking white and one for checking black. Then *foreach* position, check against the color whether or not it should cause a black, white or empty result. Remember when it's black, it cannot be white or empty, etc (think about the order of checking pawns).